# React router dom history.push('/') not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to use react router's `history.push` or `history.replace` to redirect to the root of my website (`history.push('/')`). But every time I do it just pushes to the current page (i.e. 'localhost:3000/page'). It also does push another entry into the history (which I can go back into) but it is all the same page ('/page' and not '/'). For context, I do have a `<Route path='/' exact component={...}` />`on the top of the route switch and a`` at the bottom.

Comment: Can you try removing ```exact```?

Comment: Where are you getting `history` from? Provide a [mcve]